# Remove Flutter flutter_charts PieChart space between segments

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Is there a way to remove the spaces between segments in PieChart in Flutter?
I found the way to remove the space around the chart

```
layoutConfig: charts.LayoutConfig(
    leftMarginSpec: charts.MarginSpec.fixedPixel(0),
    topMarginSpec: charts.MarginSpec.fixedPixel(0),
    rightMarginSpec: charts.MarginSpec.fixedPixel(0),
    bottomMarginSpec:charts.MarginSpec.fixedPixel(0),
  ),
```

But this doesn't remove the space between the segments

[image]

Is there some kind of config that will remove the spaces?
It is not logical that a PieChart will have spaces like that but I can't find a way in the code or and docs on how to do that.

10x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `strokeWidthPx` to `0` inside `ArcRendererConfig`:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new charts.PieChart(
      seriesList,
      animate: animate,
      defaultRenderer: new charts.ArcRendererConfig(
          startAngle: pi,
          arcRatio: 0.2,
          strokeWidthPx: 0,
          arcLength: pi),

      layoutConfig: charts.LayoutConfig(
        leftMarginSpec: charts.MarginSpec.fixedPixel(0),
        topMarginSpec: charts.MarginSpec.fixedPixel(0),
        rightMarginSpec: charts.MarginSpec.fixedPixel(0),
        bottomMarginSpec: charts.MarginSpec.fixedPixel(0),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: For me adding a strokeWidthPx: 0 was still showing some space. Instead, I used 0.01 as strokeWidthPx. But your answer pointed me in the right direction +1. thanks.